# Calculating F(Y)

Tags: probability

Give the distribution function, F(y). Be sure to specify the value of F(y) for all y, −∞ < y < ∞.

(y, p(Y));
(1, .4),
(2, .3),
(3, .2),
(4, .1)

I am a little confused by this questions and don't know how to calculate this.

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. What are you confused about?

Comment: @smanoos this is about calculating continuous probability. Apparently I can calculate it but I don't know how to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints:

- You have $\Pr(Y=1)=0.4,\; \Pr(Y=2)=0.3,\; \Pr(Y=3)=0.2,\;\Pr(Y=4)=0.1$.
- What are $\Pr(Y\le 1),\; \Pr(Y\le 2), \;\Pr(Y\le 3),\; \Pr(Y\le 4)$?
- What are $\Pr(Y\le 0),\; \Pr(Y\le 1.5),\; \Pr(Y\le 3.7),\; \Pr(Y\le 5)$?
- What is $\Pr(Y\le y)$, covering all values of $y$?

Comment: so would it be: p(Y<=1) = p(1) , p(Y<=2) = p(1)+p(2) , etc. I don't understand where you got 1.5, 3.7 and 5 for though. could you explain that?

Comment: For example $\Pr(Y\le 3.7)=\Pr(Y\le 3)=0.9$,  You can do something similar for all $y$